# High Contrast Firefox Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, contrast

I have sensitive eyes and need to be able to invert dark text on a white background in Firefox Ubuntu. So far I can't find a straightforward way to do this, and Firefox doesn't register the Ubuntu high contrast theme. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing [Dark Background and Light Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-background-light-text/). This is what the current page looks like with the entension enabled:

[image: White text on dark background]

Note that this extension only affects the contents of the web page. Depending on your gtk theme, the tabs and address bar may have dark text on a light background. To reverse that, simply click on the ☰ button at the right top corner of the browser and select *Customize*. In the *Customize* tab, click on *Themes* in the bottom row and choose *Dark*. Then click *Done* and now you'll have even the tabs and address bar with light text on a dark background as in the image above.